# Capybara with javascript and factory girl

Tags: javascript, capybara

I have one factory with inheritance

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :client do
   sequence(:first_name) { |n| "John#{n}" }
   sequence(:last_name)  { |n| "Smith#{n}" }
 factory : client_with_dialog do
   show_popup true
 end
```

On my react code I am getting from the server the client show popup value.

```
$.get('/client/get_choise')
.done(function (result) {
  if (result.show_popup) {
    alert();
  }
});
```

test code:

```
scenario 'visit page with popup' do
  client =  create :client_with_dialog

  visit_page_with_popup
end
```

On my capybara testing the popup is not showing,
My question is does the `$.get('/client/get_choise')` code actually run in tests or not?
How can I write a capybara test that will actually open the popup window?

Comment: This likely depends on your capybara and rspec configuration.  You might want to include details on the capybara browser setup (not all drivers can execute JS) and any DatabaseCleaner config you may have.  Also try to do some basic debugging and let us know if you've verified that the record is in the database during the test.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the rack-test driver which doesn't support JavaScript.  Start here https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver